# How to document a function that returns a specific object defined by the app in yard?

Tags: ruby, yard

I have a function that returns a User or nil if it can't find the user. It looks like this:

```
  # Given an access token in the HTTP headers, it returns the User who owns the token
  #
  # @return [User] the user who owns the access token
  def set_api_user
    token = /(.*)=\"(.*)\"/.match(request.headers["Authorization"])[2]
    @api_user = ApiKey.find_by(access_token: token).user
  end
```

My question is, how do I document that it returns a User or nil if it can't find it?

Comment: If find by returns and empty object won't this fail with the .user afterwards?
Perhaps you should add a:
@api_user = ApiKey.find_by(access_token: token).user rescue nil

This way it's autodocumented and safer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the behaviour of the code for error conditions etc, in Yard, you just add the alternatives into the comment:

```
# @return [User,nil] the user who owns the access token
```

The Yard renderer will do something like this with it:

---

- (User<sup>?</sup>) set_api_user

  the user who owns the access token

---

The little question mark is Yard's convention for "maybe you'll get this, or maybe you'll get nil"